# How to store the data from Active Directory to SQL Server without writing code?

Tags: sql-server-2005, active-directory

How to get data from Active Directory to SQL Server with out writing code below type of code

```
select  *  
 from  openquery(adsi, '  
select  givenName,  
sn,  
sAMAccountName,  
displayName,  
mail,  
telephoneNumber,  
mobile,  
physicalDeliveryOfficeName,  
department,  
division 

from    ''LDAP://dc=ica,dc=com''  
where   objectCategory = ''Person''  
        and  
        objectClass = ''user''  
')
```

without writing above type code, we have to connect directly AD to SQL Server.

How to connect directly AD to SQL Server using any type of tools or any simple connection?

Please post  the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no point** in duplicating the entire Active Directory contents into your SQL Server - and thus, **no such solution exists** without writing lots of code.

I've been asking over and over again: **what are you trying to do** and what is your goal?? Why do you need to duplicate the data?

If the data is already in Active Directory and easily accessible - **why** do you want to duplicate everything into SQL Server?

There are ways to extract some data from Active Directory and import it into SQL Server - but not without writing code. And there are ways to synchronize certain bits of information between AD and SQL Server - but again: code needs to be written, and caution should be taken **not** to unnecessarily duplicate too much information.

Comment: Well, this is good question. I also looking for the best way to do this... A reason is simple - I want to store some user-related data in my application and of course I can not use AD for that... The only reason for using AD is authentication in my case... but after that I'm associate AD user with my user's table in database... using SID... but I'm not sure about it, because it looks like well known users have the same sid inside trusts.